# How to write complex ClassDeclarationSyntax generator?

Tags: .net, roslyn

I am writing code that's supposed to receive a few parameters (`INamedTypeSymbol`s) and generate a huge class (I'm talking hundreds of lines) based on them, a class that's supposed to inherit from some another predefined class, implement non-predefined interface, have multiple constructors with complex logic, have a whole lot of fields of various types, declarations and usages of structs inside of it and a whole lot of other stuff.

It's a lot to write using Syntax Factories by hand, but it's all logical and deterministic.

I'm struggling with how do I design the code that's supposed to output that final class. I could break it down to a several generators, like `ConstructorGenerator`, `MethodGenerator`, `StructDeclarationGenerator` etc. but what I dislike about that, is that in the final class syntax, all of these seemingly separate parts of class definition are in fact very much intertwined with each others and rely on each other very much (same fields, methods and other members are used across difference "concerns", such as ctors, methods and other members).

Splitting up implementation into pieces that seem independent but really are very much coupled by nature doesn't feel correct.

On another hand, jamming it all into one god `ClassGenerator` class doesn't seem right either.

What would be the optimal way to approach modelling this domain?